# Instalação de Namespace

Tags: c#, namespace, .net-assembly

Eu tenho um projeto teste que veio sem o `Namespace` `System.Web.Helpers` e outros. Procurei e não achei. Deveria estar, mas não está. Ha como instalar o cara? Bem, posso caçar na internet e adicionar, mas como eu acho ser um namespace básico, gostaria de saber se há como instalar para estar disponível para todos os meus projetos. Não falo de instalar uma referência, isso não é o problema, mas sim, instalar o `Assembly` e ele ficar disponível para todos. É só achar a DLL na internet e instalar? O `Framework` é o 4.0.

Comment: Não sei se entendi mas acho que você quer colocar no GAC http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/585817/Installing-a-DLL-into-the-Global-Assembly-Cache-GA Documentação do utilitário https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.110).aspx. Fora isso não sei se é boa ideia.

Comment: Qual o tipo do projeto?

Comment: Como eu disse, não é adicionar uma referência, não é isso. É instalar o namespace no Visual Studio, para que essa DLL fique disponìvel a qualquer projeto. Estou sem essa dll no meu VS e preciso dela para muitas coisas, muitos projetos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse `Namespace` pode ser instalado usando o [`NuGet`](https://www.nuget.org/) no modo [visual](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/visualstudiobr/acelere-seu-desenvolvimento-com-o-nuget) ou usando o [console](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell). Para maiores informações sobre esse pacote acesse o [site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft-web-helpers/).

Para abrir o console você pode usar `ALT + T N O`  (`ALT` + `T` depois `N` depois `O`) no visual studio e digitar o seguinte comando:

```
PM> Install-Package microsoft-web-helpers
```

Comment: Entendi Leandro, pelo NuGet. Achei que eu tivesse que baixar em algum lugar primeiro, depois pegar essa DLL e adicionar na pasta correspondente, mas isso não iria instalar, ou seja, sempre que eu precisasse dessa referência eu não conseguiria instalar, pois fiz isso e não consegui. Obrigado.

Comment: Lenadro, dessa forma não deu certo. Talvez seja o nome do pacote que esteja errado, pois o namespace seria: system.web.helpers, system.web.mvc e system.web.webpages, esses são os namespace que preciso instalar.

Comment: Descobri o erro. Não era ponto(.) e sim hífen(-), ficaria assim: pm>Install-Package microsoft-web-helpers

Comment: Entào era o outro pacote, agora sim ;)

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, o que está faltando no seu projeto é uma referencia a alguma biblioteca (dll). O namespace é apenas uma estrutura de organização e fica disponível se a dll que o disponibilizar estiver referenciada corretamento no projeto.

Para tanto, basta chamar adicionar a referencia ao seu projeto e ele passará a ficar disponível.

Se a dll for de terceiros (não for um outro projeto seu ou da própria Microsoft - parte do framework) você precisa manter ela junto ao aplicativo e as vezes, realizar alguns procedimentos de instalação no ambiente onde vai rodar.

Se for apenas uma referência do framework, basta adiciona-la ao seu projeto e tudo ficará bem. Tenha cuidado ao trabalhar com referências externas, versões incorretas ou compilações para arquiteturas diferentes podem provocar problemas no seu aplicativo com certa facilidade.

Nesse link você pode ver como adicionar uma referência no Visual Studio:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/wkze6zky.aspx

No proprio lugar onde você encontra a referência, basta pesquisar o home "helpers"

Comment: Valeu Intruso, ms como eu disse no post, não é adicionar uma referência e sim adicionar o Namespace no Visual Studio. Estou sem ele para que pudesse adicionar a referência dele. Mas pelo NuGet, acho que eu consigo fazer. Achei que houvesse outro caminho, mas só conheci esse, pelo NuGet.

Comment: @pnet, entendo que a resposta não solucione o seu problema, mas é de grande interesse seu. O namespace é a estrutura organizacional a nível de código de uma biblioteca (física). Uma referência deve ser feita à biblioteca para então ter acesso as mesmas  a partir de seus namespaces.

Comment: @CaiqueC., não entendi seu comentário. O que eu disse no post é que a dll não estava instalada e gostaria de saber como fazer e o Intruso já me respondeu. A resposta sim, solucionou o meu problema. Não entendi, mas ok, sem problemas.

Comment: @pnet é que no comentário acima, você disse: "[...] não é adicionar uma referência e sim adicionar o Namespace no Visual Studio.". Para adicionar o Namespace é necessário adicionar a referência no projeto, sem a mesma não se tem acesso aos namespaces.

Comment: Então, para eu adicionar a referência eu preciso que ela esteja instalada no VS, certo? Aí eu vou em ADD References, seleciono Assembly e marco a referência que eu quero instalar, certo? Bem e se não há isso instalado? Eu preciso instalar antes para depois referenciar, certo? É exatamente o que está acontecendo. Eu não tenho o assembly system.web.mvc e etc. Já instalei e abri outro post pois está dando um erro de incompatibilidade de versões.